# bitbucket pipeline deployment approval

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

I have been looking for implementing deployment approval within bitbucket pipeline. Basically it's similar to Octopus deploy you can implement 'awaiting for approval' step.  Has anyone ever implemented it with bitbucket pipeline ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can trigger steps manually by specifying `trigger: manual` in your step.

See [the docs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/configure-bitbucket-pipelines-yml-792298910.html#Configurebitbucket-pipelines.yml-ci_stepstep) for more information